# Code is giving absurd answer

Tags: c++, sequences

The following code segement is to calculate sum(K*((nCk)^2)) for 1<=k<=n and for n till 10^6, but the program starts giving absurb answer for n>20.  Please help me.  I think it may be because the product is not able to store such large value but what to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%i",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%i",&n);
        double prod=1;
        if (n!=1)
        {
            for(float i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                prod = prod * (2+(i/(n-i))) ;
                prod = fmod(prod,1000000007.0);
            }
            prod = prod * n; 
        }
        else prod=1 ;   
        prod = int(prod)%1000000007;
        cout<<prod;
        printf("\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check for scanf return value. it might be causing the undefined behaviur since t is not initialized, and if scanf fails you are left with t having undetermined value

Comment: and why use printf and scanf in c++? there are more powerful native IO in c++.

Comment: I would also not rely on `int` being wide enough to be able to hold something like 20c10...

Comment: @kaushik - i am using this for fast input output cin cout are approx. three times slower than scanf and printf

Comment: and scanf is returning the correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing

```
prod = prod * (2+(i/(n-i))) ;
```

You will lose precision when (i/(n-1)) is not integral and gives recurring decimal number. This will lead to unexpected results.